# Do we can edit existing resources using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm using ARM templates to deploy resources (VMs)
Is there any way I can use ARM templates to edit already existing resources using ARM templates 
for example change the tag name of existing VM.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that, you just do the same thing when you create the resource. in arm template doesnt care if the resource exists or not, it just tries to apply the state that is in the template.

keep in mind some properties are read-only after you've created the resource, so changing those wont work (but tags are always fine). also, worth noting that it would apply the exact state in the template, so some undesired changes might slip in.